# String Comparision without Special Character

Tags: java, c++, c, scripting, string-comparison

I have strings having special characters e.g.

```
 "ravi", "Ravi" ,"!ravi","ravi...","RaVi)" etc..
```

I want all these to be treated as same. How to achieve this. 
 Can be in shell script, C,C++,JAVA.

Thanks,
Ravi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java: `str.toLowercase().replace("[^a-zA-Z]", "")` will render them all in lowercase with special chars removed and therefore all `equal()`

Edited to cover everything *not* alpha as "special"

Comment: probably better to use a regex which removes anything that the OP doesn't want (e.g. `[^a-zA-Z]`).  of course, that depends which character ranges the OP _does_ want, which isn't apparent from the question.

Comment: remove `toLowercase()` and compare with `equalIgnoreCase()` or just remove `A-Z` in regex

Comment: that replace would make *"morning"* be treated the same as *")m*#$%)_o!@#$r)(&n(*&^i(&%*&%n(*&!#$g_01241"* and I'm not sure this is exactly what the OP wants :)

Answer (score 5):

In C I'd use [`isalpha`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isalpha.html) in a loop, removing the unwanted characters before treating the string.

```
#include <ctype.h>

/* ... */

loop {
  if (isalpha((unsigned char)*src)) *dst++ = *src;
  src++;
}
```

Comment: also we need `tolower (*src)`

Answer (score 0):

Use **find** function of String in c++ to find the occurrence of your substring in your case "ravi".

```
size_t find ( const string& str, size_t pos = 0 ) const;
```

**It will return you starting index of your substring in main string.**

by using that information, you could manipulate the string as per your requirement.

[More  on string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)